# How do I write an AutoHotKey script to search and replace a clipboard string when an item is copied to the clipboard?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, script

I'd like to create an AutoHotKey script such that when a string item is copied to the clipboard, a search and replace is done on the string, and the resulting string be copied to the clipboard.  Ideally I'd like to happen automatically upon the event of the clipboard getting populated.

Pseudo-code for this might look like:

*Assume for this example that the string to be put on the clipboard is "h:\my folder"*

1. *Event of clipboard getting populated* (ideally) or if necessary, I can manually trigger the action numerous ways
2. "h:\" is replaced with "\myserver\my share\"
3. "\myserver\my share\my folder" is copied to the clipboard

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this, it should work, or at least get you started, I didn't have a chance to test it out:

```
#Persistent
return
OnClipboardChange: 
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, h:\, \myserver\my share\, All
return
```

Tested and this works for me

Comment: Perfect!  What does the initial "return" do?  The script behavior seems the same regardless of it's presence.

Comment: @Howiecamp The behavior is not exactly the same. Without the first `return` before the label (`OnClipboardChange:`), the script will jump into that method immediately (when the script starts) as opposed to when it should be called (when the clipboard changes). The result is that `StringReplace` gets executed once when it shouldn't.