# (AHK script to) Parse the clipboard contents and paste after modifying them

Tags: autohotkey, r

I am very new to AHK and struggling to  do the following

Action: copy some text which looks like ABC  2013-12-31

Desired result (by a keystroke) is to paste after modifying the original clipboard contents :  myfunction("ABC" , "2013-13-31")

Some context: I am working with [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) which is a (awesome!) IDE for [R](http://www.r-project.org/). 
In some interactive analysis , I wanted to manually submit the a portion of my output to another R function

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/444598/how-do-i-write-an-autohotkey-script-to-search-and-replace-a-clipboard-string-whe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me!

```
*F10:: ;Assign F10 key
Clipboard =   ;empty Clipboard
SendInput, ^c
ClipWait
StringSplit, word_array, Clipboard, %A_Space%, . ; Omits periods.
send myRfun("%word_array1%","%word_array2%") {Enter}
return
```

Comment: **modified from example in : http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm